# How to use css style in php

Tags: php, css, echo

Im using php to display data from mysql. Here are my css statements:

```
<style type=”text/css”>
table {
    margin: 8px;
}

th {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: .7em;
    background: #666;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 2px 6px;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

td {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: .7em;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
}
</style>
```

They are used for displaying table, tableheader, tabledate.
Im new to php css, so im just wondering how to use the above css style in php displaying codes:

```
<?php>
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><th>ID</th><th>hashtag</th></tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "<tr onmouseover=\"hilite(this)\" onmouseout=\"lowlite(this)\"><td>$row[0]</td>                <td>$row[1]</td></tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>";
<?>
```

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. You don't use them differently in PHP than in normal HTML: either include an external stylesheet or embed the stylesheet in your `<head>` element

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) is a style sheet language used for describing the presentation semantics (the look and formatting) of a document written in a markup language.
more info : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets
CSS is not a programming language, and does not have the tools that come with a server side language like PHP. However, we can use Server-side languages to generate style sheets.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>...</title>
<style type="text/css">
table {
margin: 8px;
}

th {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: .7em;
background: #666;
color: #FFF;
padding: 2px 6px;
border-collapse: separate;
border: 1px solid #000;
}

td {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: .7em;
border: 1px solid #DDD;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php>
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><th>ID</th><th>hashtag</th></tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
echo "<tr onmouseover=\"hilite(this)\" onmouseout=\"lowlite(this)\"><td>$row[0]</td>                <td>$row[1]</td></tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 26):

I guess you have your css code in a database & you want to render a php file as a CSS. If that is the case...

In your **html page**:

```
<html>
<head>
   <!- head elements (Meta, title, etc) -->

   <!-- Link your php/css file -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.php" media="screen">
<head>
```

Then, within **style.php** file:

```
<?php
/*** set the content type header ***/
/*** Without this header, it wont work ***/
header("Content-type: text/css");


$font_family = 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif';
$font_size = '0.7em';
$border = '1px solid';
?>

table {
margin: 8px;
}

th {
font-family: <?=$font_family?>;
font-size: <?=$font_size?>;
background: #666;
color: #FFF;
padding: 2px 6px;
border-collapse: separate;
border: <?=$border?> #000;
}

td {
font-family: <?=$font_family?>;
font-size: <?=$font_size?>;
border: <?=$border?> #DDD;
}
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 6):

Just put the CSS outside the PHP Tag. Here:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    table {
        margin: 8px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
    <tr><th>ID</th><th>hashtag</th></tr>
    <?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        echo "<tr onmouseover=\"hilite(this)\" onmouseout=\"lowlite(this)\"><td>$row[0]</td>                <td>$row[1]</td></tr>\n";
    }
    ?>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Take note that the PHP tags are `<?php` and `?>`.

Comment: Also, plain HTML tags like "<table>" don't need to be echoed - just output them in the HTML and  start the <?php tag when you actually need PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting your php into an html document:

Note: your file is not saved as index.html but it is saved as index.php or your php wont work!

```
 //dont inline your style

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css"> //<--this is the proper way!

 //save a separate style sheet (i.e. cascading style sheet aka: css)
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understood this `Im new to php css` but as you've defined your CSS at element level, already your styles are applied to your PHP code

Your PHP code is to be used with HTML like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    /* Styles Go Here */
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php
   echo 'Whatever'; 
  ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also remember, you did not need to echo HTML using php, simply separate them out like this

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo 'Blah'; ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Absolute easiest way (with your current code) is to add a `require_once("path/to/file")` statement to your php code.

```
<?php
require_once("../myCSSfile.css");
echo "<table>";
...
```

Also, as an aside: the opening `<?php` tag does not have a `>` on the end, and the closing `?>` php tag does not start with `<`. Weird, but true.

Answer (score 0):

css `:hover` kinda is like js `onmouseover`

```
row1 {
    // your css
}
row1:hover {
    color: red;
}
row1:hover #a, .b, .c:nth-child[3] {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

not too sure how it works but css applies styles to echo'ed ids

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question is about how to incorporate css into a php file, not on the use of `:hover`. If you have remarks for OP, leave a comment

Answer (score 0):

You can also embed it in the php. E.g.

```
<?php
    echo "<p style='color:blue; border:2px red solid;'>CSS Styling in php</p>";
?>
```

hope this help for anyone in the future.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, since it applies the style to only one element in particular. OP noted that they have a move complex css

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this is correct format or not. but it can solved my problem with removing **type="text/css"** when insert css code in html/tpl file with php.

```html
<style type="text/css"></style>
```

become

```html
<style></style>
```

Example
[image]

Comment: Please, [don't post your code/error messages as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4298200). We are not able to copy/paste from images and secondly search engines are unable to index that information. So please make sure that any textual information is actually provided in text form.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem just now and I tried the require_once trick, but it would just echo the CSS above all my php code without actually applying the styles.

What I did to fix it, though, was wrap all my php in their own plain HTML templates. Just type out html in the first line of the document and pick the suggestion html:5 to get the HTML boilerplate, like you would when you're just starting a plain HTML doc. Then cut the closing body and html tags and paste them all the way down at the bottom, below the closing php tag to wrap your php code without actually changing anything. Finally, you can just put your plain old link to your stylesheet into the head of your HTML. Works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest:
`require_once("../myCSSfile.css");`
as elbrant mentioned.

I had to add **`<style>`** at beginning of ***myCSSfile.css*** and **`</style>`** at the end (normally not needed in a CSS file).