# How do I add CSS class to a PHP line?

Tags: php, css, class

I have this line

```
<? if(!$_SERVER['HTTP_X_PJAX']){  require_once("footer.php"); } ?>
```

Is there a way that I can add this class:

```
no-tablet-portrait no-phone
```

Comment: Can't you just add those classes to a container inside footer.php?

Comment: PHP outputs HTML. Whatever HTML you output can have css classes applied to them. For example: echo `'<div class="no-tablet-portrait no-phone">'`.  You can't add it to the code above because it's not generating HTML directly.

Comment: Hope this previous thread helps: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336229/adding-css-to-php

Answer (score 1):

PHP Operates within HTML. Therefore, you can just use `<style>` or `<link>` instead, before the `<?php`

Also, you should be doing it within `footer.php`

Answer (score 0):

Edited the footer.php.

```
<div class="bg-dark no-tablet-portrait no-phone">
        <div class="container tertiary-text bg-dark fg-white" style="padding: 10px">

        All right reserved. Copyright &copy; 2014 -
        <a class="pjaxer" href="<? echo $GLOBALS["sys"]->get_url(); ?>page/tos" ><? echo lng_menu_tos; ?></a> - 
        <a class="pjaxer" href="<? echo $GLOBALS["sys"]->get_url(); ?>page/privacy" ><? echo lng_menu_privacy; ?></a> - 
        <a class="pjaxer" href="<? echo $GLOBALS["sys"]->get_url(); ?>page/disclaimer" ><? echo lng_menu_disclaimer; ?></a> - 
        <a class="pjaxer" href="<? echo $GLOBALS["sys"]->get_url(); ?>page/contact" ><? echo lng_menu_contact; ?></a>
        </div>
```

Now it's hidden on all the pages for mobile and tablets, didn't need to edit every single page.