# How to include CSS code directly in a php file

Tags: php, css

I've been searching about this for a while with no luck, I'm just curious if this is possible.

Is it possible to include CSS rules directly in a php file with no HTML code?

```
img {
  background: 0px 0px / 100% 100% no-repeat scroll rgb(12, 12, 12);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}
```

I just have this piece of code and I don't think would be necessary to create a .css file to include just this small piece of code, otherwise I will create the css file.

Comment: Unless is a one page site, i recommend to use a external file, but answering your question, you can either use echo, or close php tag (?>) write it inside style tag and open again (<?php) or put it on the style attribute inside the tag (style="blabla")

Comment: Please search for things like this before you post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483213/how-can-i-include-css-in-php   And: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336229/adding-css-to-php

Comment: @MatthewC Like I said in my post I didn't find it with luck. The ones you are pointing me to say that I can include a CSS file which is what I don't want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put it into your PHP file using `<style>` tag:

```
<style>
    img {
        background: 0px 0px / 100% 100% no-repeat scroll rgb(12, 12, 12);
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
    }
</style>
```

Or directly to image into `style` attribute.

```
<img style="position: fixed; width: ...">
```

Comment: It doesn't matter. `<?php PHP here ?> <style> img {...} </style> <?php other PHP ?>`. Or, of course, you can echo it, like `echo '<style> img {...} </style>';`. Many ways how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is just an "[inline CSS](http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningcss/qt/tipcssinlinesty.htm)" policy

Answer (score 0):

PHP runs on the server and css/html/javascript all run on a web browser, so you can't have the css in between  and I'm afraid you'll need a little html, but just a little

it should look like this:

```
<?php <php code> ?>
<style>
    img {
        background: 0px 0px / 100% 100% no-repeat scroll rgb(12, 12, 12);
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
    }
</style>
<?php <more php code if you like> ?>
```