# PHP / CSS How to work with themes for my site?

Tags: php, html, css, customization

The question is the title.

Examples are like Vanilla Forums or WordPress, which the same user can create customized themes or choose a themes among hundreds.

I find nothing related, what I wonder is a small code to know how to choose the topic you want to occupy.

Comment: So, you want to know how/what backend capabilities exist to help change front-end design?

Comment: @Adib Hello, i need know the "How".

Comment: What you're basically doing is building sites based on a user's pre-defined inputs. You save that data in the database, and you create a custom CSS file for each user. Here's an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201451/how-to-use-css-style-in-php

Comment: Apparently this is not what I need know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you would want to load a different CSS file for every theme. Maybe this can help [Dynamically loading an external JavaScript or CSS file](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml)

Comment: yes this can help me.