# Cant add style to php

Tags: php, html, css, styles

I have this little piece of code in php. How can I make it a link or add a class to it to add style? I did this to my code:

```html
<?php 
    <span class="tab"><a href="#"> 
      <?php echo "<td>" . $row["categoria"] . "</td>"; ?></a>
    </span>
?>
```

Have I done something wrong? Has anyone idea what should I do? Thanks.

I also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201451/how-to-use-css-style-in-php), but it didn't help.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand how HTML markup works, you are putting a `<td>` tag inside of a span? Also, You can't add styling to php, you add styling to HTML. - Where is your CSS? - Did you try and inspect your code to see if the link is there and it's CSS hiding it?

Comment: Where do you want to add style or class, which design do you want to see?

Comment: I want to add style to categoria row so I put a class named tab to it. My css is in another file. I dont think its neccessary,because even the href tag doesnt work

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. The span will not style the table cell. Put the class on the TD and remove the span and the A on the content: `<?php echo '<td class="tab"><a href="#">' . $row["categoria"] . '</a></td>'; ?>`

Comment: First, don't write echo every time, you can easily add class="" or style="" attribute to any html element, and also write class name or inline style inside them. You didn't see link because your html structure was wrong, you wrote <span><a>title</a></span> outside of <td> element, that is why you didn't sew link. Try to write your codes clearly it will help you to find problems easily.

Comment: @Doe what do you want to do? Where do you want to give a style can you tell us? I formatted your code below but I removed it, i think you couldn't catch it before I removed it. I will undelete it, but i will remove it again after few minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the right format of adding html classes inside php rows.`echo '<td class="tab"><a href="#"><b>' . $row["marca"] . '</b></a></td>';`

Answer (score 0):

First, don't write echo every time, you can easily add `class=""` or `style=""` attribute to any html `element`, and also write `class name` or `inline style` inside them. You didn't see link because your html structure was wrong, you wrote `<span><a>title</a></span>` outside of `<td>` element, that is why you didn't sew link.
Try to write your codes clearly it will help you to find problems easily.

```
<table>
    <?php 
      $sql="SELECT * FROM presta_prova " ; 
      $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);    
      while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row[ "marca"];?></td> 
            <td>
                <span class="tab">
                    <a href="#"><?php echo $row["categoria"];?></a>
                </span>
            </td>
           <td><?php echo $row[ "descrizione"];?></td>
         </tr> 
      <?php 
      } 
      ?> 
      </table>
```

Comment: As I commented. This question is not worth answering

Comment: Okay i will remove answer @mplungjan