# how to write html tag with inline css in php file?

Tags: php, css, string, inline

I want to run the following code for practice but can't. What do you think is wrong?
I expect a red text to appear. But that doesn't happen and the text will turn black

```
    <?php
class Myclass{
    public $font_size = "40px";
    public $font_color = "red";
    public $string_name = "just do it";
    public function print_string(){
        echo "<p style=font-size:".$this->font_size."; color:".$this->font_color.";>".$this->string_name."</p>";
    }
}
$foo = new Myclass;
echo $foo->print_string();
```

Comment: kindly post what error you are receiving.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use css style in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201451/how-to-use-css-style-in-php)

Comment: _"What do you think is wrong?"_ - your use of string / attribute delimiters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of style property must in `''`, like this :

```php
echo "<p style='font-size:".$this->font_size."; color:".$this->font_color.";'>".$this->string_name."</p>";
```